# wkhtmltopdf failed to load highcharts.js

Tags: highcharts, wkhtmltopdf

I'm using wkhtmltopdf to convert chart to pdf but wkhtmltopdf gives me an error Failed to load https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js while jquery loads fine. Any help is appreciated!

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = "Before highcharts";

        Highcharts.chart('container', {

            chart: {
                animation: false
            },

            plotOptions: {
                series: {
                    animation: false
                }
            },

            series: [{
                data: [43934, 52503, 57177, 69658, 97031, 119931, 137133, 154175]
            }],

        });
        document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = "After highcharts";
    });
</script>
```

PDF result
[image]

Comment: Hi @q t, You used a `highcharts` tag, but the problem is more related with `wkhtmltopdf`. I think that you should contect directly with autors of the project: https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/issues/new/choose. Also, you can check and consider the Highcharts exporting module: https://www.highcharts.com/docs/export-module/export-module-overview

Comment: @ppotaczek thanks for the suggestion. The pdf will have other data coming from back-end as well and from the export module, I think you can only export the chart?

Comment: @q t, Yes, but you can also get a chart in SVG and manipulate it - check this thread: https://www.highcharts.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=40382 You can find more information about the `exporting` module in the docs: https://www.highcharts.com/docs/export-module/export-module-overview